# DLL comparison to confirm If same source code is used

Tags: c#, .net, dll, asp.net-3.5

I am comparing to make sure 2 dlls are generated from same source. As I could not use external tools to compare, I just created IL files using IL disassembler and  comparing manually.

- For the below fields in a .IL file , the count is same while
  comparing.

  ```
   //   CLR method headers : 
   //   Num.of method bodies  - 
   //   Num.of fat headers    - 
   //   Num.of tiny headers   - 

   // Managed code : 
   //   Ave method size -
  ```
- Order of class names are not same while count and names are same .

Is it safe to assume for the above scenarios that both DLLs are from same source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell this.

Not only are no two compiled DLL's the same because of [the MVID and other properties that differ each time you compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735643/how-can-i-tell-whether-two-net-dlls-are-the-same): two assemblies containing the same number of methods doesn't tell anything:

- The **implementation of the methods can differ** (e.g. v1's `Foo()` method contains `return true`, while v2's `Foo()` contains `return false`)
- **Different source code can yield the same IL**.

It seems like you have an entirely different problem you want to solve, like educating your team and using continuous integration to share assemblies that are compiled on a build server.  If you can explain *why* you want to make sure two DLLs were compiled from the same source, perhaps some better answers can be given.

Comment: Thanks . The code I am currently changing is taken from the code repository environment and dll from the diff  environment.There were no changes to the code/dll for years and hence could not track the deployment process immediately.So need to confirm the dll  & code from repository are in sync.

Comment: Although you accepted this answer, I will insist that valid comparison with help of ILSpy is possible so try it, it should help

Answer (score 13):

You can use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile both DLLs. Use *Save Code...* option for both libraries, so you can save it as complete Visual Studio project (`csproj`). Then simple WinMerge (with recursion) on both directories will show you all differences in the source code.

I've recently successfully used this approach to make sure what version of DLL was used on production machines.

Comment: Beyond Compare's folder comparison feature might be a good way to compare the two folders once decompile and save the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the following -

1. try [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for an open source assembly browser and decompiler and compare the c# code generated.
2. run test cases against the classes in the assembly and validate if the results are the same.